# Remapping fonts in unicode-math has no effect on e.g. `\mscrC`

Tags: xetex, luatex, unicode-math

For some reason, in this setup, `\mathscr{C}` and `\mscrC` produce different results:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style=TeX} 
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\setmathfont[range={\mathscr,\mathbfscr},StylisticSet=0]{xits-math.otf}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathscr{C}, \mscrC
\]
\end{document}
```

In the result, `\mathscr{C}` respects the remapping, but `\mscrC` does not. I was under the impression that `unicode-math` translates the former to the latter, but it seems as if `\mathscr` here contains some additional processing that "knows" about fonts. A literal  behaves like `\mscrC`. The only thing that seems to work is *redefining* `\mscrC` after `\begin{document}` to force it to go through `\mathscr`.

1. What is `unicode-math` really doing?
2. How do I work around this?

Comment: `\mscrC` is just an alias for the  character; `\mathscr` instead does many things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think that it is not a bug but a feature: It gives you the possibility to use different fonts even if the "destination position" is the same. `\mathscr{C}`, `\mscrC` and also `\mathcal{C}` all print the char `"1D49E`. The current behaviour means that e.g. `\mathscr` and `\mathcal` can come from different fonts:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\unimathsetup{math-style=TeX}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\setmathfont[range={\mscrC,\mathscr,\mathbfscr},]{xits-math.otf}

\begin{document}
\mscrC
\[
\mathscr{C}, \mscrC,\mathcal{C}
\]
\end{document}
```

If you want to change the look of `\mathcal` too you will have to add it to the list too (like I did for `\mscrC`).

Comment: Hmmm, but the documentation seems to suggest that the remapping is on the level of character codes, rather than commands. In fact, when I tried to remap a Unicode range instead of `\mathscr` I had the same problem. But remapping `\mscrC` directly seems to work, thanks!